# proof of inferior and superior limits

Tags: real-analysis

Here is a proof on sequences of real numbers on pg 93 in "Mathematical Analysis - 1, Vladimir A. Zorich."

[image: The proof in question]

[image: Footnote for the proof in question]

Here is what I don't understand in this proof:

1) How is it that he can find a subsequence $x_{k_{1}},x_{k_{2}},\ldots, k_i<k_{i+1}$ such that $i_n\le x_{k_{n}}<i_n+\frac{1}{n}$? What is that "by induction" bit?

2) In the second paragraph,how does he take $\forall \epsilon >0 \exists n \in \Bbb N \forall k>n( i-\epsilon <x_k)$ to conclude that $i-\epsilon$ is a lower bound on any partial limit of $x_1,x_2,\dots$?
$$
\begin{array}
\ & \ & \ \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$
Here are some definitions used in the proof:

[image: Definition of a sequence]

[image: Definition of a limit of a sequence]

[image: Definition of a sub-sequence of a sequence]

[image: Definition of a partial limit of a sub-sequence (of a sequence)]

[image: Inferior and superior limit of a sequence]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Since $i_n=\inf_{k\ge n}x_k$ is a lower bound, for any $\epsilon>0$, there exists $k_n\ge n$ such that $i_n\le x_k\le i_n+\epsilon$. He just chooses $\epsilon$ to be of the form $\frac1n$. For the "induction part", he just applies this construction to construct an increasing sequence : the next $n$ considered is the first one greater than $k_n$.
2. On the contrary, by definition of the lower bound, he uses the fact that $i-\epsilon$ is **not** a lower bound.

Comment: You say next n will be the one immediately after $k_n$, but the proof reads "For the numbers $n \in \Bbb N$..." 



Say i can find a $k_1$ such that $i_1 \le x_{k_1} < i_1+1$, what guarantees I can find a $k_2>k_1$ such that $i_2 \le x_{k_2} < i_2+\frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: To be clear I am assuming "For the numbers $n \in \Bbb N$" means for every $n \in \Bbb N$. And also, in the second paragraph,  he says that $i-\epsilon<x_k$ means no partial limit of the sequence can be less than $i-\epsilon$. Why is that so?

Comment: It's a classic theorem : if a sequence $(u_n)$ has a limit $\ell$, and if for all $n$, $u_n\ge m$, then the limit $\ell$ must verify $\ell\ge m$. For the other property, it's the definition of the lower bound : if $\alpha=\inf A$, then there is $a\in A$ such that $\alpha\le a<\alpha+\epsilon$ for all $\epsilon>0$.

Comment: I understand that it is possible to find $k_1$ such that $i_1\le x_{k_1}<i+1$ and $k_2$ such that $i_2\le x_{k_2} <x_2 + \frac{1}{2}$ and similarly for all $n \in \Bbb N$.

But what guarantees $k_2>k_1$ and $k_3>k_2$ and so on? i.e what guarantees that the term that satisfies the $i_2$ inequality will come after $x_{k_1}$ in the sequence and the one that satisfies the $i_3$ inequality will come after $x_{k_2}$ and so on. What if the terms come before and only then? There is nothing in the construction preventing that

Comment: It is possible because, by definition of an infimum, if $i=\inf A$, either $i\in A$ or for every $\epsilon>0$, there is at least one element $a\in A$ such that $a<i+\epsilon$. But in this last case, there is in fact an *infinite* number of such $a$. So in your case, an infinite number of terms of the sequence $(x_n)$. So you can always suppose $k_{n+1}>k_n$.

Comment: Oh so is this what you're saying: for every $\epsilon>0$ there are infinite number of $x$ in the sequence such that  $x<i+\epsilon$?

Comment: Yes, and this is what the author uses.

Comment: But for the case of the sequence $x(n)=1-exp(-n)$ for any $i_n$, for any $\epsilon$ such that $i_n+\epsilon \in (0,1)$ there are always only a finite number of $x$'s in the sequence such that $x<i_n+\epsilon$

Comment: Yeah, but this sequence is increasing, so $\inf_{k\ge n} x(k)=x_n$ for all $n$, which does not contradict what was said before. Here there is only one limit, and the sequence $(x(n))$ itself gives an answer to what is asked by the theorem.

Comment: I think I understand now. It took me some time, but I think I got it.

Say $i \notin A$ then it cannot be the case that for some $\epsilon>0$ only a finite number of members of the sequence are such that $x<i+ \epsilon$ because then those terms constitute a finite set whose minimum would be the infimum, which contradicts $i\notin A$

And for the case that $i\in A$ i will satisfy $i\le i<i+\epsilon$

And so in either case you can always suppose $k_{i+1}>k_i$

Am I correct in my understanding?